# Is Expo tied to a specific React version?

Tags: react-native, expo

I just started using Expo for a project with SDK 32, and when initialized it depended on React 16.5.0.

I want to start using some new features like Hooks, so I upgraded the react version to 16.8.0-apha1.

However this broke the native app in a way that I don't understand.

> Unable to resolve module schedule/tracking
>   ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js: Module schedule/tracking does not exist in Haste module map.

I've tried a clean install of everything javascript (clearing caches incl Haste's) but that didn't help.

Is the Expo SDK tied to a specific React version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Expo always uses a specific React version, `16.5.0` in this case.

In their blog post about `v32.0.0` they have a section about how to upgrade an app based on a previous SDK, in it they tell you to use a specific version of React.

> - react to "16.5.0" — (**this exact version**)

You can read about it [here](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v32-0-0-is-now-available-6b78f92a6c52), look in the **Upgrading Your App** section for all the dependencies and versions tied to `v32.0.0`.

Comment: If you wish for an ETA you could ask on their forums!

Comment: I expect they already do their best to keep up with the latest react version as well as they can. I'm not sure asking for an ETA would help anything, but I might give it a try.

Comment: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-react-1680-aka-hooks 

Comment: How about for newer Expo SDKs? They don't mention `react` version anymore.

Comment: If they don't mention a new version in their patch notes it's because the version you should be using is the same as the last release.